# nc command can't lookup DNS name

Tags: dns

I have lots of clients need to check if the port is opened on remote server. I use nc command to do this job, however it always give out DNS lookup failure, but I can successfully find the DNS record by using the dig or nslookup.

Anyone knows the reason? Thanks!

```
[root@client ~]# nc  -vzw5  d1.myserver.com 443 
d1.myserver.com: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host : No such file or directory
[root@ndc-nz1-1 ~]# nslookup  d1.myserver.com
Server:         192.168.1.155
Address:        192.168.1.155#53

Name:   d1.myserver.com
Address: 192.168.2.25

[root@client ~]# dig d1.myserver.com

; <<>> DiG 9.2.4 <<>> d1.myserver.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11270
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;d1.myserver.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
d1.myserver.com. 7200 IN A    192.168.2.25

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.155#53(192.168.1.155)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 21 21:13:21 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

File info on nsswitch.conf

```
[root@client ~]# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf |grep 
hosts: files dns 
[root@client ~]# ll /etc/nsswitch.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1658 Apr 1 2008 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

File info on resolv.conf

```
[root@client ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.155
options timeout:1
```

Trying other commands:

```
[root@client ~]# ping d1.myserver.com
ping: unknown host d1.myserver.com
[root@client ~]# wget d1.myserver.com
--01:47:57--  http://d1.myserver.com/
           => `index.html'
Resolving d1.myserver.com... 192.168.2.25
Connecting to d1.myserver.com|192.168.2.25|:80... connected.
```

Comment: What does `stat /etc/hosts` say? The "no such file..." leads me to believe your local name resolution may have trouble.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root root 138 Mar 24  2013 /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Please add that information to your question so everyone can see it easily

Comment: Can you `ping -c1 d1.myserver.com`? (I'm more interested in name resolution than the ping itself.) Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @roaima Like your guess, the name resolve got failed.

Comment: That's a strange error message. If I try the same `nc` with an unknown hostname, I get `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`, which I'd expect. `Unknown host : No such file or directory` suggests something else is wrong. Please paste the contents of `resolv.conf` too. Is it only `nc` that gives DNS errors or do other commands give them too (eg, `ping`, `curl`, etc)?

Comment: @mjturner I've appended in the question

Comment: Can you try removing the `options timeout:1` line from `resolv.conf` and see if it makes a difference? As the issue seems intermittent I can only thing that as some points the name resolution takes longer than 1 second, causing your problems.

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf. You probably have not configured the system to use DNS to resolve host names.  nslookup and dig don't bother looking to see if the system is configured to use DNS to resolve hostnames. They use DNS regardless. (Though if you don't specify a server, they will use /etc/resolv.conf to find a DNS server to use.)

You want to see DNS in the hosts line, something like `hosts:  files dns`

Comment: Hi @tim-b The dns has configured in nsswitch.config. [root@client  ~]# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf |grep dns
 
hosts:      files dns
[root@client  ~]# ll /etc/nsswitch.conf 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1658 Apr  1  2008 /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: @NeilWang please add that information to your question so everyone can see it easily.

Comment: I think some glitches happened on this serer, I replace "hosts:  files dns" to "hosts:  dns" in nsswitch.conf and then flush the DNS cache, it is working property, and then change back to "hosts:  files dns", everything goes smoothly again.